# Unix Group Permissions

Tags: permissions, unix, chmod, groups, chown

I have created a directory and chown to have permissions master:webmaster and chmod the folder to 775 hence group writeable. So why is it i bert as a member of webmaster cant mv the directory or create a file inside the directory.

Answer (score 4):

To mv the directory you will need write permission on its parent.

But you ought to be able to create inside the directory; can you show us this failing?  The output of

```
ls -la /the/directory
id -a
touch /the/directory/file
```

would be most interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the permissions for the parent directory are too restrictive (no write permission for group)

Comment: or in other words: on UNIX, directories have their own set of permissions.